# Cannot log in to phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, linux, phpmyadmin

I have a strange problem - I cannot log in to phpMyAdmin. Yesterday all was OK.

I go to mysite.com/phpmyadmin page, it works ok, but, when I am trying to log in to every DB it just drops the password and nothing happens. The sites on these DBs works ok as always however.

Comment: Try restarting pretty much everything, as well as double checking your phpmyadmin configuration. It may have attached to a mysql user, and if that user or password changed, that could be your issue.

Comment: I restarted apache2, and I did't do anything with mysql user, this is the strangest part... The only thing I did yesterday was installing sass and compass.. But can it be the issue?

Comment: Have you tried to connect to MySQL server through command line?? If not try to connect it through command line and what out put you are getting, just post it here

Comment: Thanks, the issue was finally not enough space on disk, error.log helped.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help someone.

The problem was that not enough space was left on the disk.